# How to send API data from client-side to server-side [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I should get data from 2 APIs in a server-side. I need to call User API by using `projectApi.projects[i].id` as an id parameter for the User API Url.

I'm sure there must be errors in `server.js` and `index.ejs`.

I'm trying to print out:

- `(projectsApi.projects[i]).name`
- `((JSON.stringify(usersApi.group)).user[j]).username`

Is there any way that can make it possible?

**Project API**

**url :** /projects?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{ 
  "total":2000,
  "projects":[ 
     { 
       "id":123,
       "user_id":435400,
       "name":"Project Name"
     },
     ...
   ]
}
```

**User API**

*Project ID = 123*

url : /projects/**123**/group?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

```
{ 
  "total":1,
  "group":[ 
           { 
             "id":1,
             "user":[
                  { 
                      "id":435400,
                      "username":"User Name"
                  }
              ]
           }
         ]
}
```

**service.js**

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

    var id = req.params.id;
    var url_project = '/projects' + apiKey;
    var url_user = '/projects/' + id + '/group' + apiKey;

    Promise
      .all([rp({uri: url_project, json:true}), rp({uri: url_user, json:true})])
      .then(([projectsApi, usersApi]) => {
          res.render('index', {projectsApi, usersApi});
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
      });
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
        <% for (var i = 0; i < (projectsApi.projects).length; i++) { %>
                <div><%= (projectsApi.projects[i]).name %></div>

                <% for (var j = 0; j < (JSON.stringify(usersApi.group)).user).length; j++) { %>
                    <% if ((projectsApi.projects[i]).user_id == (JSON.stringify(usersApi.group)).user[j]).id) { %>
                        <div><%= ((JSON.stringify(usersApi.group)).user[j]).username%></div>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %> 

        <% } %>
```

Comment: Please share collection ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `service.js` looks good. Instead of using `for` loops in `ejs` template, I would simply generate a single list (in `service.js`) and pass it to a template.

```
Promise.all([rp({uri: url_project, json:true}), rp({uri: url_user, json:true})])
      .then(([projectsApi, usersApi]) => {
          let usersList = usersApi.group.map(g => g.user);
          usersList = usersList.flat();
          const finalList = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < projectsApi.projects.length; i++) {
            const object = {};
            object.projectName = projectsApi.projects[i].name;

            for (let j = 0; j < usersList.length; j++) {
              if (projectsApi.projects[i].user_id === usersList[j].id) {
                object.userName = usersList[j].username;
              }
            }

            finalList.push(object);
          }
          res.render('index', {finalList});
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
      });
```

In your template -

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < finalList.length; i++) { %>
    <div><%= (finalList[i]).projectName %></div>
    <div><%= (finalList[i]).userName %></div>
<% } %>
```

**Edit**

Looks like `flat()` won't work here since it's not implemented yet. You can do one of the two things

1) `usersList = usersList.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])`

2) use a library like `lodash` which provides a `flatten()` method

`userList = _.flatten(userList)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the thing is that I have to know `projectApi.projects[i].id` in ejs (client-side) and use it as a parameter for `id` in User API which is server-side (/project/id/team) and show the data on ejs client-side.

This has to be defined before `Promise` rendering urls.
`var url_project = '/projects' + apiKey;
var url_user = '/projects/' + projectApi.projects[i].id + '/group' + apiKey;`

Comment: @HyewonJoo In that case just add project id to `object`. `object.projectId = projectsApi.projects[i].id;`